# Less substantial second edit not automatically rejected

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I have full editing privileges and edited a first post in the review queue. Then, after opening the suggested edits queue, I found [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2650565). The linked edit is submitted as suggested against my revision, but based on the original post.

I know that if someone edits a post you're working on in the meantime, the system rejects your edit if it's less thorough than the most recent revision, and you're shown the notification bar with a message about this.

My edit was submitted first and is also much more substantial. Why didn't the system reject the linked suggested edit as being less thorough than mine?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what happened, as far as I can tell.

1. Lucas Eduardo clicked the "edit" link first when it was still enabled and started writing.
2. You clicked "edit" from within the review queue, while Lucas was still writing.
3. At 06:24:35 you submitted your edit.
4. At 06:25:09 Lucas submitted his suggested edit.

If #3 and #4 would have been reversed i.e. Lucas submitted the suggested edit first then we would have seen Community rejecting the suggestion without a reason but since he posted the suggestion after yours was already in place, the system simply merged it.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean that if the SE had been submitted first, my (non-suggested) edit would've been rejected, since I expect his would've gone to /review as normal? I also don't think I was clear enough in the question; I'm wondering why it was merged instead of rejected.

Comment: No, if the suggested edit was in the queue before you submitted your edit, your edit would have auto rejected it, it happens a lot when people edit quickly. Full edits can't be rejected, only merged. Can't see a way to explain it better, sorry!

Comment: Only one more vote until blue wizard wins :P (in your profile)

Comment: Now people are just spamming clicks :P One is over 50 already!

Comment: @Doorknob and you're among the click spammers? ;-) No worry, plan to replace that with something more interactive soon. :)